# How to extract domain from Email Address in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to select `domain name` from an email address using `Athena` but my noob glasses cant find the translation that works.

As per my understanding the following should work but the required functions are missing in `Athena`

`(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(sd_ccode, strpos(sd_ccode, '@') + 1),'.',1)) as Domain`

would you know how these functions translate in Athena ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [split_part](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#string-functions) function, as in:

```sql
select emailaddress , split_part(emailaddress,'@',2)
from table1
```

Comment: wow that was simple!

Answer (score 1):

One more method using regexp_extract function:

```
regexp_extract(emailaddress ,'@(.*)',1)
```

Regex `'@(.*)'` here is a capturing group after @ containing any number of characters